# Output the loop in masm

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, masm

I'm trying to simply output `CX`'s values (binary) in `loop l1` with `OutBin proc`, but it gives me only its first value (10).

I guess there's some problem with the loop itself, with saving registers before calling procedure, but I don't know how to fix everything.

```
 .model small
.stack 100h
.data
  ;  X dw 10  DUP (1,2,3)
.code
.startup
  mov cx, 10
  l1:
    mov ax, cx
    push cx
    call OutBin
    pop cx
  loop l1

OutBin proc
; AX to print
    mov bx, ax
    mov cx, 16
  ob1:
    shl bx,1
    jc ob2
    mov dl,'0'
    jmp ob3
  ob2:
    mov dl, '1'
  ob3:
    mov ah,2
    int 21h
  loop ob1
;call NewLine
OutBin endp

NewLine proc
    mov dx, 0Dh
    mov ah,2
    int 21h
    mov dx, 0Ah
    mov ah,2
    int 21h
NewLine endp 

.exit
end
```

Comment: Single-step your code with a debugger to see where the path of execution goes.  (Hint, you forgot to `ret` at the end of your functions).

Comment: @PeterCordes many thanks, missing `ret` was really a mistake. After executing, though, console freezes, not asking me press any key to return to editor or something

Comment: **Use a debugger** to see if your code reaches an exit system call or not.  And if not, where it gets stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has 2 procedures *OutBin* and *NewLine*. Both are missing the `ret` instruction just above their `endp` directives.

What your program also misses is a descent exit to DOS.
Look what happens when the *l1* loop has finished.

```
loop l1

OutBin proc
```

The code mistakenly falls through in the *OutBin* procedure. You'll have to insert the necessary intructions to return to DOS:

```
loop l1

mov ax, 4C00h   ;DOS.TerminateWithExitcode
int 21h

OutBin proc
```

---

### Some additional debugging

> ```
> X dw 10  DUP (1,2,3)
> ```

Guessing that your ultimate goal is to display 10 numbers (`mov cx, 10`) taken from the array *X*, this `dw` directive is actually defining 30 numbers.

```
1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3
```

That's probably not what you wanted.

Notice that once you start reading from the array *X*, you'll have to setup the segment registers first. With `.model small` they don't automatically point to your `.data`. If you used `.model tiny`, they would though.

---

### A small but important improvement

> ```
>   shl bx,1
>   jc ob2
>   mov dl,'0'
>   jmp ob3
> ob2:
>   mov dl, '1'
> ob3:
> ```

The above code can be simplified to the much better:

```
mov dl, '0'
shl bx, 1
adc dl, 0
```

If no carry was shifted out, the `dl` register will remain '0'.
If a carry is shifted out, the `dl` register will get incremented to '1'